# Click event for AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm working in the Flash IDE with ActionScript 2, and need to check for a click event on a specific object(button) named "btn_play".

This is what I have so far:

```
btn_play.click = function()
{
    trace("Hi");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question, can you explain little more , please?

Comment: Basically I need a function that will be triggered when a specific button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right ,  you need first to change your code like this:

```
btn_play.onRelease = function(){
   trace("btn_play has been clicked");
}
```

And in this way you can easily detect if the element has `onRelease` handler:

```
if(btn_play.onRelease){
   trace("btn_play has onRelease handler");
}
```

Comment: @TomMcPadden great , it means i'm still remember AS2! But may i ask why you're using it?

Comment: Sure! I'm making a basic music player but I couldn't get the sound file to play when clicked, despite all the tutorials I read through :P Thanks again!